# How to show a notice to plugin update

Tags: wordpress

I would like to show an admin notice (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) when my plugin has a update.

**Like this:**

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your plugin is in the WordPress repository, then you can do this by hooking into the WordPress update functionality. Note that `get_site_transient()` is always used by falls back to the `get_option()` when it is not a multisite install..

```
// Your plugin file
$plugin = 'plugin-dir/plugin-file.php';

// Check for Plugin updates, if you want to (not recommended for all pages)
// wp_update_plugins();

// Results of the update check
$update_plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
if ( isset( $update_plugins->response[ $plugin ] ) ) {
    // Your plugin needs an update
}
```

In the result of `update_plugins` the `$update_plugins->response` is an `array()` that will be something like this:

```
'response' => 
  array (
    'plugin-dir/plugin-file.php' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => '12345',
       'slug' => 'plugin-file',
       'plugin' => 'plugin-dir/plugin-file.php',
       'new_version' => '1.2.3',
       'url' => 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dir/',
       'package' => 'https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/plugin-dir.1.2.3.zip',
    )),
),
```

Comment: For me, even though there are updates available, response array is blank. Any idea why it may be blank?